# Inject input's value into Orbeon service request

Tags: orbeon

I have created a POST request that is performed after some defined action.

Here I have its body:

```
<json type="object">
    <variables type="object">
        <customerId type="object">
            <value ref="control-1">CUSTOMERID</value>
            <type>String</type>
        </customerId>
    </variables>
</json>
```

What I'm trying to do is to get value from `control-1` and replace the `customerId->value` value. It doesn't work. However, I noticed that setting `name=` instead of `ref=` makes the value empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to set service request value using XPath in action's editor:

```
/json/variables/customerId/value
```